# Why is the value returned the first in my select no mather what i choose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

it is late and this is probably a very simple fix, i have seen several posts her on stackoverflow covering this, but i cant seem to get this to work right now.

To the case, i have a select with 7 options. All options have a number from 1 to 7 in their value fiels.

**html**

```
<select id="thecase" name="thecase">
    <option value="1">Velg hva saken gjelder:</option>
    <option value="2">Transportskade</option>
    <option value="3">Stengt bestilling</option>
    <option value="4">Finansiering</option>
    <option value="5">Ros & ris</option>
    <option value="6">Bedrift</option>
    <option value="7">Annet</option>
</select>
```

**javaScript**

```
var hiddenOpt = jQuery("#option_other");
var target = jQuery('#thecase');
var caseVal = target.val();
hiddenOpt.hide();
target.change(function(){
    alert (caseVal);
    if (target == 'annet') {
        hiddenOpt.show();
    };
});
```

When i try this bit of code it returns value 1 no mather what.
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Danbannan/QM2U8/

Could someone explain to me what i am missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually by looking at my code.

The right answer to this is:

```
target.change(function(){
    caseVal = this.value;
        /*Not the target, the caseVal*/
    if (caseVal == '7') {
         alert (caseVal);
        hiddenOpt.show();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

put `var caseVal = target.val();` inside `change` function. The first time the `select` value is 1 and that is saved in `caseVal`, But you need to get the value when the `select` value changes, henceyou need to get the `target.val()` inside the change function. you can also use `$(this).val()`

http://jsfiddle.net/QM2U8/2/

Comment: Oh my that IS embarrassing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
var caseVal = target.val();
```

You're getting the value right away, but never changing it in the `.change()` function

It should be

```
target.change(function(){
    caseVal = this.value;
    if (target == 'annet') {
         alert (caseVal);
        hiddenOpt.show();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var caseVal = target.val();
```

This is defined only at the **`onload`** event.  Hence it is *static*.  So you have to make it *dynamic* by initializing in **`change`** event.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/QM2U8/3/

```
var hiddenOpt = jQuery("#option_other");
var target = jQuery('#thecase');
hiddenOpt.hide();
target.change(function () {
    var caseVal = target.val();
    alert(caseVal);
    if (target == 'annet') {
        hiddenOpt.show();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `caseVal` is get value before event.
So you need to change like this:

```
target.change(function(){
    caseVal = $(this).val();
    alert (caseVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Fix:

```
var hiddenOpt = jQuery("#option_other");
var target = jQuery('#thecase');

hiddenOpt.hide();
target.change(function(){
    var caseVal = target.val();
    alert (caseVal);
    if (target == 'annet') {
        hiddenOpt.show();
    };
});
```

Your variable caseVal was residing outside the target.change function, so it was getting, and always getting the inital value.  Put it inside to update.. voila